# Редактирование темы подсветки синтаксиса Visual Studio Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

Уважаемое сообщество, подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли (и, если можно, то каким образом) при редактировании темы подсветки синтаксиса в **VS Code**, сразу **видеть изменения, без перезагрузки окна программы?**

*Процесс:* например, понравилась какая-нибудь тема **VS Code**; загрузил, установил; но некоторые детали подсветки хочется поменять; редактируешь **JSON** темы, сохраняешь — но, чтобы изменения увидеть, нужно перезагружаться, и так столько раз, сколько вносишь изменения.